# How compensating balance works?

Tags: banking

> Assume a clothing store needs a 100,000 line of credit (LOC) to
>   manage its operating cash flow each month. The store plans to use the
>   LOC to make inventory purchases at the beginning of the month, and
>   then pay down the balance as the store generates sales. The bank
>   agrees to charge a lower interest rate on the LOC if the clothing
>   store deposits a $30,000 compensating balance. The bank loans the
>   clothing store’s compensating balance to other borrowers, and profits
>   on the difference between the interest earned and the lower rate of
>   interest paid to the clothing store.

From https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/compensating-balance.asp

Why can't the bank provide only 70,000 loan to the clothing company at an adjusted equivalent interest rate?

I can't see the value of compensating balance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the bank *could* do that, but it prefers to hold the $30,000 as collatoral on the LOC since presumably this clothing store is a relatively high-risk client.

Comment: So in the worst case if the clothing store defaults then the bank only loses \$70,000? They could also do that if they loaned \$70,000 to the clothing store.

Comment: @user253751 this is like arguing that instead of paying 10% down on a mortgage for a \$100,000 house, the bank should let you pay 0% down on a mortgage for a \$90,000 house.